# Language Model compare probability scores between Length varying sentence

Tags: probability, normalization, natural-language, language-models, perplexity

My question is : How can I compare Language Model(`LM`) score for two sentences with different lengths ?

Probabilities are `< 1`, and since `LM` scores for a sentence are multiple of probability of bigram or trigram, depending upon it's a bigram or trigram model, the probability of scores of longer sentences will mostly be smaller.

So, how should I normalize the value of scores according to length ?

I am pretty sure, atmost everyone after reading `LM` would have had same doubt. But I couldn't find much on internet.

Would appreciate for any leads on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, it's good idea to have some kind of averaging. Since in LM probabilities get multiplied, geometric average seems like a good fit.

From [Speech and Language Processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/3.pdf)

> In practice we don’t use raw probability as our metric for evaluating language models, but a variant called perplexity. The perplexity (sometimes called PP for short)
>   of a language model on a test set is the inverse probability of the test set, normalized
>   by the number of words.
>
> $PP((w_1, ...,w_N)) = \sqrt[N]{\dfrac{1}{P(w_1, ...,w_N)}}$